# Parameterized constructor for assignment

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

I've noticed some behaviour which I can't understand in parameterized constructors. Given the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    int x;

    A() {}

    A(int i) : x(i){
        cout << "A\n";
    }
    ~A(){
        cout << "dA\n";
    }

};

int main(){
    A p;
    p = 3;
    cout << p.x << endl;
    p = 5;
    cout << p.x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I get as output:

```
A
dA
3
A
dA
5
dA
```

This means that using `=` triggers the parameterized constructor, destroys the object on which it's called and creates a new object. 
I cannot understand this behaviour and I can't find the answer in the standard ( I am sure it is there somewhere, but it may be stated in a sophisticated way). Could someone help me with an explanation?

Comment: As far as the Standard goes, there are several sections relevant to what's happening. `A(int i);` is a converting constructor.  Since no `operator=` is user-declared in `A`, members `A& operator=(A&& rv);` and `A& operator=(const A& lv);` are implicitly declared.  The expression `p = 3` does overload resolution, which determines that both `operator=` are viable using the converting constructor as part of an implicit conversion sequence and that `operator=(A&&)` is the better overload....

Comment: ... Binding parameter `A&& rv` to the expression `3` using the implicit conversion sequence with a converting constructor in it means creating a temporary object of type `A`, which gets destroyed at the end of the full-expression `p = 3`.

Comment: Just a small addition: to avoid any implicit conversion you could have a look at the explicit keyword ... if you add this to your ctor with one argument the compiler will disallow the code you've written and you can more easily spot potential errors in object assignment/creation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The phrase you're probably looking for is "implicit conversion".

If you add a copy constructor and an assignment operator, and then give each object a unique ID, it's easier to see where things go:

```
int counter = 0;

class A {
public:
    int id;

    A(): id(++counter) {cout << "A(): " << id << "\n";}

    A(int i) : id(++counter) {cout << "A(" << i << "): " << id << "\n";}

    // Don't copy the id.
    // (This isn't used anywhere, but you can't see that it's not used unless it exists.)
    A(const A& a) : id(++counter) {cout << "A(" << a.id << "): " << id << "\n";}

    // Don't copy the id here either.
    A& operator=(const A&a) {cout << id << " = " << a.id << "\n"; return *this;}

    ~A(){cout << "destroy: " << id << "\n";}
};

int main(){
    A p;
    cout << "p is " << p.id << "\n";
    p = 3;
    cout << "p is " << p.id << "\n";    
    p = 5;
    cout << p.id << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
A(): 1
p is 1
A(3): 2
1 = 2
destroy: 2
p is 1
A(5): 3
1 = 3
destroy: 3
1
destroy: 1
```

As you can see, the parameterized constructor is used to create a temporary object whose value can be assigned to `p`, and that temporary is destroyed immediately after that.
You can also see that `p` is alive and well until the very end.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth answer. It really helped me understand.

Answer (score 5):

With a statement like

```
p = 3;
```

what you're actually doing is

```
p = A(3);
```

which really translates to

```
p.operator=(A(3));
```

The temporary `A` object created by `A(3)` of course needs to be destructed, it is *temporary* after all.

The object `p` itself will not be destructed by the assignment.